# How to include JavaScript in WebView Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have a small HTML/CSS/JS application. I want it to transfer on Android. I understood that it possible to make with React Native or WebView, but as my application is small i decided to use WebView. HTML and CSS are working good, but JS isn't.
Here is code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected WebView calculator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // init
        calculator = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.calculator);

        // settings
        calculator.setInitialScale(1);

        WebSettings webSettings = calculator.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        // load
        calculator.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/calculator/index.html");

    }
}
```

Is it necessary to build a bridge between JS and Java via interfaces? If answer is yes it would be mean that almost all code will be written on Java and i don't see a reason to make it with WebView because i can make it all in java. I don't want to write on Java.

Comment: Perhaps create a short example that can be used to reproduce your issue in this case show some html with some javascript that isn't working?

Comment: all work is fine in desktop version (browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript didn't worked because of version conflict. Some of new features of JavaScript doesn't work in Android 5.1.